# React Native prints error finding images despite successfully showing them

Tags: react-native, expo

In a react-native and managed expo app, I have constantly this error printing in the console for all my images.

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./assets/img/pic` from ``: 

None of these files exist:
  * assets\img\downArrow(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js ...
```

pic.png is an image that I am calling that way 
`<Image source={require('./assets/img/pic.png')} />`
in a component at the root of my app.
Despite the image has a png extension, react native is looking for files with extension .ts, .tsx, ...

I can see the image beeing displayed correctly when I am using the app, but the error is still printing!

In the **app.json** file, I put this line

```
 "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/**"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"]` in `app.json`

Comment: Coming from Low Quality Review, can you add a little more about why this works?

Comment: I'm using this snippet in one of my project, and it's working fine.